# Operator-> line of code does not work in 000webhost

Tags: php

```
   '<ul id="size" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">'.  
   '<li><a href="#">'. $name = $dbc->query("select Name from jobseeker where Email = '$email'")->fetch_row()[0] .'</a></li>' .

   '<li><a href="Logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> </span>Logout</a></li>
   </ul>'
```

I always get the Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' when I open it in the uploaded website but it works fine when I open it in the localhost.

I think the operator -> is causing this error and I dont know how to edit it out. Is there any alternative to this line?

```
 $name = $dbc->query("select Name from jobseeker where Email = '$email'")->fetch_row()[0]
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/a3098330/public_html/Website/header.php on line 32. Line 32 is the one with the $name variable

Comment: It works fine in the localhost by the way

Comment: Compare the versions of php running on localhost vs your webhost. The webhost is most likely running 5.3 or lower, as referenced in the duplicate post suggestion.